# text block insert below each line using a vi and/or sed editor

Tags: sed, vi

I have a need to insert a block of text below each line using the 'vi' and/or 'sed' editor. The block of text that needs be inserted below each line is as follows ( means a blank line):

```
first line.
second line.
...
n-th line.
<empty line>
```

Before insert, the text will look like as follows:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
...
This is the last line.
```

After insert, the text will look like as follows:

```
  This is the first line.
    first line.
    second line.
    ...
    n-th line.
    <empty line>
  This is the second line.
    first line.
    second line.
    ...
    n-th line.
    <empty line>
  ...
  This is the last line.
    first line.
    second line.
    ...
    n-th line.
    <empty line>
```

Anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your block text to be inserted was saved in a file called `block`, the file you want to process called `file`:

gnu sed:

```
sed -r '/^/r block' file
```

Comment: This works beautifully, except I have to pipe the output to a file or add the **-i** switch, i.e. *sed -i -r '/^/r block' file*, to overwrite the existing file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version.

```
awk '{$0=$0"\n first line.\n second line.\n ...\n n-th line.\n"}1' file
This is the first line.
 first line.
 second line.
 ...
 n-th line.

This is the second line.
 first line.
 second line.
 ...
 n-th line.

...
 first line.
 second line.
 ...
 n-th line.

This is the last line.
 first line.
 second line.
 ...
 n-th line.
```

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it works as described, except the output needs be directed to a file. Thank you.

Comment: @user3767809 Just add `> newfile` after the command to get it to a file

Comment: Yes and that will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do a recording. If the block is small, you can type it, else you could read from a file.
For eg, for the following text,

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
...
This is the last line.
```

1. Place your cursor at the beginning of the first line and type **qa** to start a recording of the name **a**
2. Follow this with actually typing the block of text: **o**  and then type the block

```
first line.
second line.
...
n-th line.
```

3. **Esc+j** (return to command mode and move to the next line)
4. **q** ( to stop recording)

After this point, the beauty of the macro starts.
Now you are on the original second line of the file. Type **@a**. You will find the block of text added below the original second line and the cursor moving to the original third line.

Or, if you know the original file had n lines. you could type **n-1@a**. The block of text will get added below all the lines.